# Sliding number of distinct users who get access, from one database table?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, count, grafana

My table contains at least first-name (each unique) and last-access (seconds since Epoch) :

```
|   first-name        |    last-access    |    
------------------------------------------
      John                 1592811924
      James                1592810901
      Oliver               1592811924
      Alfred               1592812925
      Alan                 1592813124
      John                 1592813924
      James                1592814040
```

How can I graph the number of distinct users who get access per hour for example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple option is:

```
select 
    floor(last_access / 60 / 60) * 60 * 60 last_access_hour, 
    count(distinct first_name) no_distinct_users
from mytable
group by last_access_hour
```

This counts distinct users per hour. You can also express this with the modulo operator:

```
select 
    last_access - last_access % (60 * 60) last_access_hour, 
    count(distinct first_name) no_distinct_users
from mytable
group by last_access_hour
```

If you want to display the epoch timestamp in a human-readable format, you can use `from_unixtime`

```
select 
    date_format(from_unixtime(last_access), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:0') last_access_hour, 
    count(distinct first_name) no_distinct_users
from mytable
group by last_access_hour
```

Comment: Great answer GMB, remains for me to plot the resulted table in grafana